# remaining vertices on Blender 2.81

Tags: modeling

in Blender 2.81

how can I be sure that there are no vertices, edges and faces left in my 3D model?

if it is found that there are leftovers which is the fastest and easiest way to delete them?

thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Do you mean unconnected (free floating) vertices?

Comment: no

I mean vestices, edges and faces that can be created by mistake in modeling

Comment: I think you might need to clarify what you mean, since if you removed all the edges, faces and vertices, you wouldn't have a model anymore.

Comment: You can select inverse of objects, select loose, non-manifold, or interior faces for example, but I don't really understand the goal of your question. It might help to add some more info to help clarify what you mean by *leftovers*.

Comment: I'm talking about hidden vertices, edges and faces that damage the mapping and texturing

Comment: use "merge by distance" to clear double vertices and "degenerate dissolve" for zero area faces